# How can I replicate a google docs default document?

Tags: document-classes

I want to replicate this google docs format. Those who have a degree in latex programming please please please please please please please please please please please please please please help me.

1. The fonts are different even though I call the usepackage function with times as the argument
2. The bolding is different for the sections.

Google docs

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15AXu65Itz5TxXLLxGOKg4AZsQs6bQX_TkV7GFIImtfQ/edit

[image]

Latex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\large Title} \\
{\large Name (Email)} \\
\hline

\section*{Introduction}
\section*{Research Question}
\section*{Methodology}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge}{\thesection}{1em}{}` to the preamble. Off-topic: replace `\hline` by something like `\hrule height 1pt` or so. But I think what you really want are some headings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the appearance of the sections, you can use `titlesec`. And I think you really want a page header. So you could do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=1in,top=1.6in,headheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge}{\thesection}{2em}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\large Title\\
Name (Email)}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
Some text for the introduction.

\section*{Research Question}
Some text for the research.

\section*{Methodology}
Some text for the methodology.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems to be closer to the target output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @Kong You're welcome! Happy Holidays!